# AS3 - Detect moving direction based on accelerometer

Tags: actionscript-3, accelerometer

The code below moves a movieclip based on the accelerometer. How to detect in which direction it moves or if it stands still?

```
import flash.sensors.Accelerometer; 
 import flash.events.AccelerometerEvent;

 var my_acc:Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
my_acc.setRequestedUpdateInterval(50);

 my_acc.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, onAccUpdate);
 function onAccUpdate(e:AccelerometerEvent):void{

 my_dot.x -= (e.accelerationX*10);


if (my_dot.x < 0) { 
 my_dot.x = 0; 
 } else if (my_dot.x > stage.stageWidth) { 
 my_dot.x = stage.stageWidth; 
 } 


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the real acceleration vector with

```
Sqrt(accelerationX^2 + accelerationY^2)
```

Then, you get the direction in degrees with

```
Cos^-1 (accelerationX / realAcceleration)
```

Try the following:

```
var accVector = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e.accelerationX,2) +
                          Math.pow(e.accelerationY,2))

var direction = Math.acos(e.accelerationX / accVector)
```

and note that you get `direction` in radians!

If you want deegrees: `var directionDeg = direction * 180/Math.PI`

If your `accelerationY` is negative, you need to change the sign of `directionDeg` and (if you want) add 360 to always get a positive number.

Comment: Also: var accVector = Math.atan2(accelY, accelX), which is equivalent.

Comment: @ejbytes Yes, but I think you wanted to write that `direction = Math.atan2(...)`, not `accVector`. Wikipedia states that *atan2(y, x) is the angle in radians between the positive x-axis of a plane and the point given by the coordinates (x, y) on it*.

Comment: var accVector = Math.atan2(accelY, accelX) * 180/Math.PI; which is equivalent. As you know in physics, the angle of the velocity vector is the same as the path vector. It's a shorter calculation, is the reason I posted my comment.

Comment: Yes, but in my exampleaccVector is a length, in your example is an angle.
`direction` is equal to `atan2(accelY,accelX)`, not `accVector`!
Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes you are right. I posted that comment while looking at something similar while researching some other code and it was VERY late, or should I say early :)

Comment: It's fine, it was just to be sure. I never used atan2, so I wanted to be sure I understood correctly what you were saying.